# pandas splitting letter and number mix column based on pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split

I have a sample database with one column:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
 
 'question#': ['a1.2','a10','a10.1','b11.1a','k20.3d','b20c']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

it looks like this:

```
Out[8]: 
question#
0       a1.2
1       a10
2       a10.1
3       b11.1a
4       k20.3d
5       b20c
```

there isn't any way to sort number and letter mixed column correctly, so i thought the only way to do that is to first split the column into 3 columns:

**first column:** a letter: (a-z), the string always starts with one letter

**second column:** two possible outcomes:

1. single digit or multiple digits:  (1-9)+

   OR
2. digits + '.' + digits: (1-9)+(/.)(1-9)+

**third column:** a letter or nothing:   (a-z)?

so for the sample database i want it to split into the following columns, **DESIRED OUTPUT**:

```
Out[8]: 
question#  firstcol   secondcol    thirdcol
0             a         1.2
1             a         10
2             a         10.1
3             b         11.1           a
4             k         20.3           d
5             b         20             c
```

is the syntax something like this page? i am not sure how exactly to write the regex syntax:

https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_regex_to_create_columns.html

```
  df['firstcol'] = df['question#'].str.extract(not sure the syntax, expand=True)
  df['secondcol'] = df['question#'].str.extract(not sure the syntax, expand=True)
  df['thirdcol'] = df['question#'].str.extract(not sure the syntax, expand=True)
```

Comment: What is your desired output for the sorting?

Comment: it's there but i added the words 'desired output' to the part , hopefully it's more obvious now

Comment: start with `df['firstcol'] = df['question#'].str[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df[['firstcol', 'secondcol', 'thirdcol']] = df['question#'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)(\d+\.?\d*)([A-Za-z]*)', expand = True)


    question#   firstcol    secondcol   thirdcol
0   a1.2        a           1.2 
1   a10         a           10  
2   a10.1       a           10.1    
3   b11.1a      b           11.1        a
4   k20.3d      k           20.3        d
5   b20c        b           20          c
```